# Codemirror initial bindings

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am using Codemirror. My code doesn't use ES6 modules. I would like to know
how to get at the `Vim` object? On the Codemirror Vim readme, we see:

```
import {Vim, getCM} from "@replit/codemirror-vim"

let cm = getCM(view)
// use cm to access the old cm5 api
Vim.exitInsertMode(cm)
Vim.handleKey(cm, "<Esc>")
Vim.map("jj", "<Esc>", "insert"); // in insert mode
Vim.map("Y", "y$"); // in normal mode
```

(I am especially interested in `.map`). However this gives an error if used in a `<script type="module">...</script>`
in an HTML file due to the `@replit` bit. How do I get at the Vim object within a `<script>` in HTML?
I am getting Codemirror via the following

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.0/mode/markdown/markdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.0/keymap/vim.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly I found the answer shortly after posting the question.

We can simply do, for example,

```
CodeMirror.Vim.map("jk","<Esc>","insert")
```

So the Vim object appears inside the CodeMirror object.